# Can there be such a thing as pure a priori thinking?

Tags: kant, apriorticity-and-aposteriority, transcendental-idealism

Having read Kant's Critique of Pure Reason, and in fact just finishing a second read after some time, I've been trying to develop a suitable "worldview" about the structure of the mind.

I believe I am something of a subjective idealist when it comes to the world generally, and this is due to my inability to fully disconnect empirical from a priori experiences.

But am justified in that?

From various sources (Husserl, Levinas, etc) we find that "consciousness is consciousness of *something*". So, when it comes to a priori thinking (intuitions, knowledge, etc), I fail to understand how such an entity can be fully "pure". (Reflecting, I daresay Kant himself does not mention pure a prior entities).

I see it as this: A priori and a posteriori entities exist as 'gradations' against each other, wherein an empirical object can never truly be distinct from a mind, and likewise an a prior intuition (say) can never truly be distinct from a body.

Having said that, I think I can grasp a little of Transcendental Idealism, in the sense in which objects can exist within themselves, albeit distinct from experience (do I have that right?).

In short, the question is as the heading.

Comment: Brentano's thesis that consciousness is intentional ("of something") is accepted by the phenomenological tradition, but controversial. Anti-intentionalists contend that there are "phenomenal" mental states that are *not* intentional, even derivatively, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/#InteExhiAllMentPhen). The problem with "pure *a priori* thinking" lies elsewhere, all proposed candidates for it were shown to surreptitiously mix in some very *a posteriori* (and oft mistaken) input.

Comment: See [D'Agostini, sec.5](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/09672550110058821) for an interesting historical perspective on phenomenological tradition:"*The wide interest in the nature of pure thought and pure theory... was partially connected to the effort made by philosophy to save its own primacy and identity... However, it was not on behalf of pure thought that the battle was won. On the contrary, the very adjective ‘pure’ soon began to fade, and the
research culminated (for Heidegger since the 1923 winter courses on Faktizität) with the victory of impure existential thought.*"

Comment: Or the modern neuroscientist perspective vis-a-vis Dean Buonomano, “the first thing the brain knows is the body”

Comment: Since you've read CPR twice you must already intuitively believe or tend to believe pure a priori thinking from somewhere contingently. Re your "an a prior intuition (say) can never truly be distinct from a body", Kant stressed pure intuition has to ground to sensibility from a body not unlike contemporary embodied cognition principle, so in this sense they never be truly distinct though utterly heterogeneous. But for your "an empirical object can never truly be distinct from a mind", Kant's thing-in-itself object surely exists but can be truly distinct and inscrutable from an arbitrary mind..

Comment: Being conscious of thought is within pure reason, is it not?

Comment: Thanks to all. I think my question has been answered... But @DoubleKnot, you say, and I agree, that a "thing-in-itself object surely exists..." but distinct from an arbitrary mind. Could not the same logic be applied to an a priori entity at the "other end of the scale" so to speak? I feel, however, there may be a paradox here, since in this case we must be talking about other people's thinking, which for us would not be noumenal.

Comment: @JKusin - obviously :-) I' my body. As Whitehead said: "No one ever says, 'Here am I, and I have brought my body with me.' "

Comment: I don't think we have major difference here since for you your empirical object perhaps means the empirical concept of that thing-in-itself object. Object seems not a well defined concept in CPR. Thus if in above sense they're not entirely distinct too since they have their own (impure) type of intuition grounding. Ideally your terminology and wording should be more exact according to Kant's fashion when talk about his sytem, mind here is somewhat vague and inaccurate, empirical concept may be more felicitous. And for Kant the jump in such gradation is the key thesis to be discussed...

Comment: @Double-Knot Well apologies for lacking scientific precision of terminology, although you have failed to provide alternatives. Yes, by empirical concept I mean a noumenal thing-in-itself. By mind I mean the manifold of intuitions wherein is contained the substratum for all a priori objects, that is personal, private, and within itself. By objects I mean noumenal entities, that could represent intuitions or knowledge; the "nugget" of thought. I wonder if you have any to add about this idea of an a priori entity with a purely extremal existence?

Comment: The jump between such gradation is perspicuous for most of us unless everyday you can experience wonderful new a posteriori entities/things to form or significantly change your metaphysical a priori first principles, and Kant just wanted to bring this to our attention and further tried to critique such pure a priori reason as mind capabilities due to its intrinsic limitations. But in general the true idea of an a priori entity as a thinking thing certainly exists eidetically and materially adequately as those necessary truths such as LNC either in platonic heaven or in mundane human minds...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, I must admit I'm sceptical. I'm very much siding with a realist view of things, in the sense in which I could understand pure a priori entities only in terms of the _structure_ of thinking. On the other hand, I can understand a relativist point of view, in the sense in which _every_ example of an intuition or "thought" is purely a priori in relation to that arbitrariness so characteristic of the physical universe. Otherwise, I have no concept of a platonic heaven, or purely metaphysical realm.

Comment: I intentionally used platonic heaven *or* human minds exactly in case you're not a realist of platonic heaven but only of the latter, there's a way to connect them in some structure of thinking *outside* of a particular human mind. Now just under your view you can mentally remove that 'uncomfortable' realm from my above comment. And such jump was so manifest in Kant that he didn't even need lots of a posteriori empirical experiences outside his little hometown for his entire life to love, study and critique this rational structure/realm of human minds. Do you agree my above perspicuousness?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot I can understand this idea of _a priori_ knowledge independent of experience, but only in the sense in which they would be universal structures of cognition, common to every individual, such as space and time. I see what you mean when you talk of Kant not needing abundant empirical experiences in order to do his work. However, employing this idea of pure a priori knowledge, I am led to a subjective idealist viewpoint, that ensures for me the existence of _other people's_ experiences, although I can not have access to them.

Comment: Kant's transcendental idealism posits existence of other people's experiences as (self) mind-independent noumena while acknowledging them uncognizable in themselves (one has no access to them is a reason), thus it's subtly different from Berkeley's/Yogacara's subjective idealism, though one cannot infer anything else useful further upon this mere difference... Sure no two people's phenomenal consciousness about their empirical experiences would be exactly same as no two leaves would, but we can share distinctly and clearly understood a priori concepts by the said common structure of mind...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Thank you. I think I'm with you now. I agree that individuals share a common structure of the mind. However, now it's on paper, I'm beginning to suspect that there would be subtle differences for each member. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Kant says that **we cannot even think purely without being given an intuition**. If we're speaking of *a priori* pure thought, this intuition is the pure intuition of time or space (cf. B161 for distinction between pure/formal intuitions and forms of intuition). We find an example of how to do that in the *Analytic of Principles*, especially in the *Schematism* chapter, where pure logical categories are applied to the pure intuitions of time producing pure time-determinations. Later, the whole of *Transcendental Dialectic* is a demonstration that thought cannot produce its own content, i.e. that it constitutes mere combination of already given content, which is spatio-temporal not due to nature of thinking itself, but due to contingent matters regarding the form of our sensibility. Therefore, there cannot be pure *a priori* thought without something given from sensibility, albeit neverthless purely, because the given is the form of sensibility.

I assume your confusion is due to the assumption that pure *a priori* thought would involve nothing but logical categories. But Kant insists that it is only **in applying those categories to the formal intuitions of time and space** that any knowledge can be acquired, in contrast with the later German Idealists, beggining already with Fichte.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer will depend on how broad the definition of thought is.

The brain sends signals to the heart to keep it beating and lungs to enable breathing. If these qualifify as thoughts then they could be considered candidates for pure apriori thought. These occur in the earliest stages of development and start without the benefit of experience or even consciousness.